# Except() and Intersect() doesn't work correctly - LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, ienumerable

I am not really sure why this is not working correctly. Is it possibly because I am trying to use the expressions on a data class instead of a single field in that class?

`adminOnlyGroups` is supposed to return the groups that the admin has and the user doesn't but it is returning all of the **admin** groups

`userOnlyGroups` is doing the same, it is returning all of the **user** groups

`commonGroups` is supposed to return the groups that they have in common which there are two of, but it is returning null or empty

**Data Class**

```
[DataContract]
public class InvestigatorGroupData
{

    [DataMember]
    public int InvestigatorGroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string InvestigatorGroupName { get; set; }

}
```

**Snippet of my controller**

```
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> adminGroups = proxy.GetInvestigatorGroups(adminId);
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> userGroups = proxy.GetInvestigatorGroups(userId);

// Groups that admin has and user doesn't. These will be enabled and unselected
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> adminOnlyGroups = adminGroups.Except(userGroups);

// Groups that the user has and admin doesn't. These will be disabled and selected
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> userOnlyGroups = userGroups.Except(adminGroups);

// Groups in common. These will be enabled and selected
IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroupData> commonGroups = adminGroups.Intersect(userGroups);

if (commonGroups.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    return View("Error");
}
```

Comment: You need to define equality members for your class.

Comment: Where did you define IComparable? Otherwise you are checking objects being same.

Comment: It looks like your code is using reference equality but you'ee expecting equality based on an Id property. Write an appropriate IEqualityComparer and pass it to Except.

Comment: @ceting IComparable is only used for ordered collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement  an equality comparer for objects

This has been answered before here
[Using Linq Except not Working as I Thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824749/using-linq-except-not-working-as-i-thought)

Please see the blog post below from MSDN for further explanation
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx

If you are anonymous types it will work differently without an equality comparer. Here is an example code

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/and-equality-for-all-anonymous-types.aspx

Comment: If you find a duplicate question you should be *voting to close the question as a duplicate* not posting a link to the duplicate in an answer.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I wasn't planning to score points for posting duplicate links. Just trying to be helpful here. I will however give you a vote for suggesting this. Thanks

Comment: The blog worked perfectly, thanks a lot!