# Linq to SQL logic error and returns no values when comparing 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

I am trying to compare 2 lists and return items that don't match by comparing 3 fields inside those lists. For example

```
List<Chemical> mList = mresult.ToList();  -- less 5 items
List<Chemical> xList = xresult.ToList(); -- 7 items -- need 2 items back

foreach (var List in xList )
{
    if (!(mList .Exists(x => x.MSD_ID == List.MSD_ID)) && !(mList .Exists(y => y.Roman_ID == List.Roman_ID)) && !(mList .Exists(z => z.Source_System_ID == List.Source_System_ID)))
    {
        Chemical x = new Chemical
        {
            MSD_ID = List.MSD_ID,
            Roman_ID = List.Roman_ID,
            Source_System_ID = List.Source_System_ID
        };
        unmatchedList.Add(x);  --need 2 items but returns none
    }             
}
```

I really want to know where I am missing it. Thanks all in advance

Comment: have you checked if all the Conditions of the IF statement are true or not?
If they are true then it'll certainly not return anything... @Ram

Comment: So you have three predicates - I would execute each of them separately and store the results in local variables, making it easier to see what's going on as you debug.

Comment: Additionally, why are you declaring `xList` and never using it?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I edited the question. I will do as you said and see..... I am actually comparing with each item of xList with all the mList items to see if something didn't match.

Comment: @khaled4vokalz - Let me try doing that.

Comment: But still no sign of you doing the diagnostic work to see which predicate is failing.

Comment: And note that at this point, you're barely using LINQ to SQL, so you should be able to reproduce this in a short but complete program just using LINQ to Objects. (Only you first two lines use LINQ to SQL)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I did put those 3 comparisons into 3 bools and one of them is false all the time.  !(mList .Exists(z => z.Source_System_ID == List.Source_System_ID))..  Its a string and see no difference in both the strings I am comparing.

Comment: So why isn't that in the question? Please don't withhold information from people who are trying to help you.

Comment: The problem is with the logic (I believe).  You are checking each individual property to see if it exists, rather than if a record with all 3 properties matching. I believe the if statement you are looking for is `if (!(mList .Exists(x => x.MSD_ID == List.MSD_ID && x.Roman_ID == List.Roman_ID &&  x.Source_System_ID == List.Source_System_ID)))` but I believe the answer I gave below is better.  You would get better answers if you provided sample input and expected output.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I just did what Khaled adviced and ended up with finding which one exactly is throwing false..

Comment: Additionally, you might consider using `.Any` instead of `.Exists`, same syntax, same effect, but more universal.  `.Exists` only works in List, while `.Any` works on any collection (including List).

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, you should provide your definition of the Chemical class, as well as sample data for mList, xList, and what your expected output is.  You will get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package from NuGet and use:

```
List<Chemical> mList = mresult.ToList();  -- less 5 items
List<Chemical> xList = xresult.ToList(); -- 7 items -- need 2 items back
var unmatchedList = xList.ExceptBy(mLlist,x=>new {x.MSG_ID,x.Roman_ID,x.Source_System_ID});
```

Alternatively, you can implement IEqualityComparer like as shown here: [List.Except is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988209/list-except-is-not-working)

If your Chemical class only has those 3 fields, then just:

```
List<Chemical> mList = mresult.ToList();  -- less 5 items
List<Chemical> xList = xresult.ToList(); -- 7 items -- need 2 items back
var unmatchedList = xList.Except(mLlist);
```

Comment: Did you mean Except instead of ExceptBy, by any chance ??

Comment: No.  ExceptBy is a function in MoreLinq.  It's similar to Except but you can provide the fields to compare rather than writing a IEqualityComparer for Except.  Except by default will compare all fields.

Comment: If Chemical only has those 3 fields, then Except will work just fine, but since you didn't include the definition of it, I assumed there was more to it than just those 3, but maybe that was a bad assumption.  Updated answer in case Chemical only has 3 fields.

Comment: When I used Except, it is coming back with all the values from the bigger list. Because it is failed with Source_System_ID comparison and it always returns false. Its a string field and they look the same to me. :-(  I will change the question with what we found so you understand what I mean. Thanks for the help, Robert..

Comment: Need sample inputs.  It shouldn't be doing that, so I'm not understanding what the issue is.

Comment: It's possible (though not likely) that the Source_System_ID is using a slightly different Unicode representation of the string and is causing it to fail.  Possibly.  Then we would need to look at how the strings are being compared, and if the comparitor is doing so correctly (Case insensitive/diatric insensitve compare might fix it, maybe).

Comment: var unmatchedList = xList.Except(mLlist); this actually was helpful. Thanks a lot Robert....