# Identify process id of word instance using System.Diagnostics.Process object

Tags: c#, ms-word, system.diagnostics, word-automation, word-automation-service

I have code which starts Word application instance as follows

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
app.Caption = "abcd_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

I now need to know process id of the word instance that was started.
I cannot use FindWindow to get window handle and GetWindowThreadProcessId to get process id from handle as the code does not work on Windows server 2008.

I get all word processes by using *Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD")*.
Is there any property of Process which can give me value that we set in app.Caption ?
If not, is there any other property of Word.Application which I can set and later on read from Process array to identify correct instance of Word ?

Comment: When I execute you code, Word is not started?

Comment: its just a snippet.. not full code.

Comment: Ok, did you tried `Process.MainWindowTitle`?

Comment: May this should work for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814936/get-pid-from-word-applicationclass

Comment: I have tried MainWindowtitle.  Its empty.
Our code was same as code here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814936/get-pid-from-word-applicationclass)
But it breaks on windows server 2008. Works fine on server 2003.

Comment: Is there only ever one instance of MS Word? there is antother solution that could work, but is a bit hacky..

Comment: If I do not find anything, I can use Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD") before and after creating word instance. I can look at new PID in later process list.
Are you suggesting same thing ?

Comment: Something similar, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use the Process.MainWindowTitle property to judge if the process is by your code.

But there's some limitation:

1. When you using new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(), the word windows is not visible by default. When it's hidden, the Process.MainWindowTitle is empty. So you show set it visible before you get the Pid.
2. After you open a document, the MainWindowTitle will change to the document's file name.

Here's my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string uniCaption = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Word.Application oWordApp = new Word.Application();
        oWordApp.Caption = uniCaption;
        oWordApp.Visible = true;

        Process pWord = getWordProcess(uniCaption);

        //If you don't want to show the Word windows
        oWordApp.Visible = false;

        //Do other things like open document etc.
    }

    static Process getWordProcess(string pCaption)
    {
        Process[] pWords = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
        foreach (Process pWord in pWords)
        {
            if (pWord.MainWindowTitle == pCaption)
            {
                return pWord;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What about that (untestet):

**Updated**

```
Word.Application wdapp;
try 
{     
    Process wordProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Path to WINWORD.EXE");
    wdApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
} 
catch (COMException) 
{
     Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
     wdapp = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 }
```

The `wdApp` should be the started word.
And you get the process id through `wordProcess` instance.

Comment: I could get process id using this code.
However GetActiveObject throws following exception  
  
    _System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"
    Source="mscorlib"
    ErrorCode=-2147221021
    StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid& rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)_