# Match process to COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com, .net-4.0

I have the processes list from `Process.GetProcessesByName()` and the objects list from `UCOMIRunningObjectTable.EnumRunning()`.

How to match process to COM object hosted by that process?

For example I have 10 `notepad.exe` sessions and I want to find which session does not have any file opened and send a command to open a file. I use another app which exposes an API, this is just an example.

Comment: That is *forbidden knowledge* in COM.  If a process publishes objects in the ROT that it wants to be identifiable by the process ID then it will use a moniker that lets the client code select it.  There's nothing that Notepad will do to make this easy, it is a simple program without an Automation interface.

Comment: Thanks, but again, Notepad is given as an example.

Comment: The COM object has to publish information by itself using regular COM interfaces, otherwise there is no official way. Example of various ugly hacks with Word: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814936/get-pid-from-word-applicationclass